# Does MongoDB maintain write ordering in a replica set?

Tags: mongodb

I am using a single replica set MongoDB. My question is around sequencing of writes if there are multiple clients that write to a same document concurrently.

Scenario:
Client 1 - write to doc1 at t0
Client 2 - write to doc1 at t0+delta

Will MongoDB guarantee that client 1 write happens and then client 2 write happens?

I have read multiple document from MongoDB and suspect that write ordering is not supported so write from any of the two clients can happen first. But I just want to confirm.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by, "verify with the SQL database where the data is already present". Also, what have you tried so far? Have you researched any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wiredtiger storage engine, the order will be maintained as mentioned below.

1) client 1 will take an exclusive write lock on doc1, so no other write are operations allowed for doc1 until the lock is released.

2) Once the client 1 completes the write and the lock is released, client 2 will take exclusive write lock on doc1 and the same process will be followed as step1.

So the order here will be maintained.